# combine files using awk based on matching two first columns, then output the text of the first file and the third column of the second file

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to match two files by the first two columns. So column 1 and column 2 of file 1 should be same as column 1 and column 2 of file 2. Then if they match, output column 1 and column 2 of file 1 followed by column 3 of file 1 and column 3 of file 2.

Very similar questions to this have been asked on here before, but I have spent hours trying to figure out this code, which I am sure reflects my actual lack of understanding of awk.

I have two files which look like this, with the same first two lines and a different third line. In one file the values repeat, in the other file they do not.
file one:

```
 
 TE_00000002DNA/DTC SRR6323060.1    0.04
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    152.38
```

file 2:

```
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    4
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    4
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    4
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    5
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    6.5
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    9
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    24.16666667
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    24.16666667
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    29.2
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    29.2
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    29.2
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    3.081081081
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    3.194444444
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    36.75
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    5.565217391
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    6.55
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    7.882352941
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    74.5
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    9.066666667
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    9.066666667
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    NA
```

The output should look like this, for example:

```
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    4 0.04
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    4 0.04
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    4 0.04
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    5 0.04
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    6.5 0.04
TE_00000002DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1    9 0.04
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 24.16666667 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 24.16666667 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 29.2 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 29.2 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 29.2 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 3.081081081 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 3.194444444 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 36.75 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 5.565217391 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 6.55 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 7.882352941 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 74.5 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 9.066666667 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 9.066666667 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
```

I have tried the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1 FS $2] = $1 FS $2; next} {ind = $1 FS $2} ind in a {print a[$0], $0}'

awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0 {print c[$0],$0}'

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;a[$2]=$2;next}($1==a[$1])&&($2==a[$2]){print a[$0],$0}'

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;b[$2]=$2;next} {print a[$0],$0}'
```

Among other variations on this theme. If you can help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the underlying logic?  Why are you just picking of `NA` value but not the numerical ones from file2 and why only 5 times?

Comment: It was just a short example of the output, I have to make it manually so I wasn't going to do it for all of them.

Comment: If so, please provide a consistent input with fewer records.  Currently there aren't any clues what the criteria is.

Comment: @user2472414 if the expected output you post isn't **the** output you expect from the sample input you post then we have no way to test a potential solution to see if it works or not. Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and the output you expect given that input so we can help you. Hint: any time we need a scroll bar to see anything in your question then that thing (input, output, or code) is too big. See [ask].

Comment: Ok, I have tried to improve the question by making the input and output complete.

Comment: You just posted the output from my answer as expected output and at the same time claiming it's not working?

Comment: But the output's about 50 lines long and now it looks like file1 only contains 1 line. If you have input that's more than 1 line then provide sample input that's at least 2 lines. If you post a file1 that's no more than 5 lines and a file2 that's also no more than 5 lines plus the expected output given those 2 input files **then** we can try to help you. Make sure your input covers all your use cases for matching/not matching.

Comment: Also - when you say `the same first two lines and a different third line`, do you really mean "column" rather than "line"? If so correct that, if not explain what that means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job (unless you only want this to show lines w/ `$3 == N/A` (which your own attempts don't suggest):

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1" "$2]=$3}{print $0, a[$1" "$2]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: given your sample snippets with the one with the repetitions being file2 in my example it does exactly what you're asking .. if your files look different than your sample data please put the correct data in the question.

Comment: You are right, I tried your code with my file names reversed. It works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if the files sorted as shown, you can

```
$ join <(sed -E 's/ +/~/' file2) <(sed -E 's/ +/~/' file1) | sed 's/~/  /'

TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 24.16666667 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 24.16666667 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 29.2 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 29.2 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 29.2 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 3.081081081 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 3.194444444 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 36.75 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 5.565217391 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 6.55 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 7.882352941 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 74.5 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 9.066666667 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 9.066666667 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
TE_00000161DNA/DTC  SRR6323074.1 NA 152.38
```

not sure why your expected output doesn't include all of the above?

Comment: This doesn't match the first and second columns, but its very close! Output is: TE_00000004DNA/Helitron SRR6322978.1 1.59 SRR6322966.1 NA
TE_00000004DNA/Helitron SRR6322978.1 1.59 SRR6322966.1 NA
TE_00000004DNA/Helitron SRR6322978.1 1.59 SRR6322966.1 NA

Comment: Please clarify what doesn't match. Where did '/Helitorn` come from?  Comments not good for formatted data.  Please update your question with sample inputs and matching output.  Otherwise it's trial/error, not very productive.

Comment: I am trying to match by the first two columns of both files. So column1 in file 1 and column 2 in file 1 needs to match column 1 in file2 and column 2 in file 2. This is matching only column 1 it would appear. Because SRR6322978.1 should be matched to the same value not SRR6322966.1